# Why application die since call webservice?

Tags: android, web-services

i call 1 webservice with ksoap2 as:

```
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);                
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidhttpTranport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,
                    ContantSystem.TimeOut);

            androidhttpTranport.call(SOAP_ACTIONS, envelope);

            Object responseBody = null;
            try {
                responseBody = envelope.getResponse();
            } catch (SoapFault e2) {

            }


            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody.toString());

            } catch (JSONException e1) {

            }
```

If the result of the webservice is json (this json has 6401728 character  `'string(6401728)'`). My application dies when I call this webservice.
But if result of webservice is json '`string(2101728)`. My application runs ok.
So. Where is the error in my code? what Causes the error, is it the limit of json, the webservice or where? 
How fix this problem?
Can you help me? Thanks.

Exception:

```
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1851
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:432)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:642)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1419)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextText(KXmlParser.java:2056)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.DM.readInstance(DM.java:34)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readInstance(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:462)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:420)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:289)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:422)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:149)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at jp.osaka.APPLIActivity.getMarterDB(APPLIActivity.java:408)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at jp.osaka.APPLIActivity.access$0(APPLIActivity.java:390)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at jp.osaka.APPLIActivity$myrunable.run(APPLIActivity.java:369)
11-07 19:54:41.283: E/AndroidRuntime(10620):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Traces? Or error codes? How would we know what happened?

Comment: my app die at androidhttpTranport.call(SOAP_ACTIONS, envelope);

Comment: What is the thrown exception?

Comment: show error: 11-07 19:46:31.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9909): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1800
11-07 19:46:31.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9909): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
11-07 19:46:31.145: E/AndroidRuntime(9909):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: This isn't a solution, as such, but I'm pretty sure you'll find that the problem is ksoap. It's an old effort last updated, it would appear, in 2006 and in my experience even if you get past this problem it will only lead to a worse one.
Unless your XML is very, very complex you're probably better off parsing it yourself with the SAX APIs available from within Android.

Comment: @Phillip Fitzsimmons: Is it limit of ksoap2?

Comment: I'd characterise it more as a question of best practice - SOAP is an expensive protocol and should be avoided altogether in mobile applications (in favour of JSON, for example) or, if it must be used (such as in the case of a legacy system) then the treatment should be as lightweight as possible and whatever this might mean it certainly means no cumbersome frameworks like ksoap.

Manually parsing an XML stream in Android is very easy and has the added advantage of allowing you to discard data that your application doesn't need.